# How to specify where OkHttp should save each response on disk for caching?

Tags: caching, picasso, okhttp

I want to tell OkHttp where to save each response on disk. Basically I want to specify the file path for each response that would be saved for caching. Then later OkHttp should access this path to see if response is available in cache or not. I know we can set cache directory path BUT I want to set "cache file path" for each request.

Can i make use of interceptors in some sense to handle disk caching for each request and then make use of provided path to get/set file from/to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp can’t do this. Instead it sounds like you want your own disk persistence scheme instead of OkHttp’s cache. You can do that with an interceptor. Be careful about deleting files when the cache is at its limit!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please provide any quick code snippet suggesting which particular methods interceptors should i be focusing on. Can you provide a quick flow as to how can i setup interceptor to achieve this? I spent my entire weekend to understand but still not sure. Thanks!!!!

Comment: You'll want to build your own version of cacheWritingResponse() from [CacheInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/cache/CacheInterceptor.java).

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Really made my day.